# Как справиться с ошибкой включения telegram bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

У меня есть бот telegram, но со временем или сразу после запуска он получает ошибку соединения. Чтобы написать бота, я использую библиотеку "telebot".

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bottoken/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x02FB6910>, 'Connection to api.telegram.org timed out. (connect timeout=3.5)'))
```

Как справиться с этой ошибкой и попытаться включить бота, пока он не включится?
Пробовал:

```
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
try:
   def connect():
       bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
except ConnectionError as e:
    connect()
```

И такой вариант:

```
    res_connect=False
while res_connect!=True:
    try:
        res_connect=False
        bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
    except Exception as err:
        res_connect=False
```

Comment: Если вы пытаетесь запустить его на сервере который находится в России, то могут быть проблемы из-за блокировок РКН. Нужны прокси.

Comment: Нет. Он на сервере находящимся не в России.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У метода `bot.polling` есть параметр *none_stop*, который по умолчанию равен **False**

Если данный параметр равен **True**, то бот не будет останавливаться при какой-либо ошибке

Пример:

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
# ваш код, объявляющий команды и прочее
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Посмотрите на исходный [код](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/telebot/__init__.py#L376). Там все параметры описаны